# Surround object (semitransparent png alpha) by dashed line

Tags: images

I'm turning a cartoon image into a stencil <del>cartoon template (I'm stuck with my English here - I mean the paper with holes that let the paint through)</del>.

This is the original image:

[image: Yellow submarine cartoon]

I simplified it, so that the white and yellow areas can be separated:

[image: submarine yellow template]

But the final product that is printed should look like this:

[image: word yellow using amelia font]

That is, the yellow parts should be surrounded with black dashed line and then deleted/hidden. The knife will then cut wherever the dashed lines are.

I have no idea how to achieve that. I need a program to make a path around the image's alpha channel. Then make this path dashed.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is the word you're looking for, silk screen? As in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_printing

Comment: But we're using color spray. And the details will be finished using brushes and paints.

Comment: @TomášZato Is [Stencil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil) the word you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's it. In my native language, we call that a template (šablona). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**In photoshop:**

I found a [neat video tutorial](http://www.iceflowstudios.com/2012/tutorials/photoshop-cs6-beta-shape-strokes/) that goes over how to do this in Photoshop CS6. As far as I'm aware this is not available in any prior version. In the past you had to follow some more [work intensive methods](http://graphicssoft.about.com/cs/photoshop/ht/apsdotlinepath.htm).

**In Illustrator:**

1. Create your shape
2. Duplicate the shape, take out the fill, and open the stroke window
3. Check "dashed line" adjust stroke as needed.

Result:

[image]

You can do this with text as well, though I only know how to do it if you turn the text into outlines (right-click >> create outlines)

Then go to Object >> Path >> Offset path

Ungroup the objects and adjust the stroke of the outermost shape to be dashed.

This information was taken from the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/how-to-make-striped-dashed-border-for-a-cut-out-coupon-style) site.

Comment: I didn't know there was a SE site dedicated for that. I'll refer there next time.

Answer (score 0):

Solid border can be easily created with gimp. Using the wand tool, you can select individual fragments:

[image: selected piece with the same color in GIMP]

After this, you go into `Selection > Border` and you get thin selection (I suggest 1 pixel) around the object.

[image: border selection in gimp]

After this, you use brush. It's ideal to paint into a new layer, using the generated selection. You'll end up with something like this:

[image: black thing]
<sup>I created smaller image to save space and bandwidth</sup>

This is definitely not very pretty, nor is it dashed line. But it's what I'll use if I don't get better ideas.